# Handling input of CTRL+D with fgets() in C

Tags: c, loops, fgets

I am taking standard input from the user with a do-while loop and have included basic error handling:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int validateInput(char *buffer, int bufferSize)
{
    if (fgets(buffer, bufferSize, stdin) == NULL) /* If fgets() errors */
    {   
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Malformed input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char buffer[1024];

    do
    {
        printf("\nInput stuff: ");
    } while (validateInput(buffer, sizeof(buffer)) == 1);

    return 0;
}
```

The code runs fine, and there's a second `if` statement (not shown but hence the second argument to the function) after the first checking for buffer overflow which works perfectly fine too.

The issue is if I input `CTRL+D` on it's own (`<some input> then CTRL+D` works fine), the code will output the `printf` and `fprintf` indefinitely, not allowing any further user input.

I suspect it's a quirk with not correctly flushing the input stream or something, but so far my solutions haven't worked.

Comment: Your `validateInput` will consider ^D as "malformd input" as it stands. Also you can't input anything after you passed EOF. So what is the surprise? You should *terminate* the program once EOF is detected, not retry.

Comment: Control-D is used by Unix shells/terminals/systems to send any currently typed input to the program immediately, instead of holding it for Enter or another event. When you type text and control-D, the program receives the text. When you type control-D at the start of the line, the terminal immediately sends the input typed so far (none) to the program. So the program receives zero characters, which it interprets as end-of-file. Control-V is commonly used as a quoting mechanism, so typing control-V then control-D may send a literal control-D to the program, rather than sending pending input.

Comment: @EricPostpischil So when CTRL+D is used, it not only sends any typed input immediately (in this case nothing) but also for any future inputs until the program exits?

Comment: If you really need to, you can call `clearerr(stdin)` to clear the end-of-file condition.

Comment: @adam: No, control-D just sends the current input immediately.